# What are some good audio software for Tascam US 2000 interface?

Tags: audio-recording, software, mixing, home-studio, windows

I am looking for some good recording and mixing software to use with my new Tascam Us 2000 interface on my windows 7 64 bit PC. Preferably ones what ar'nt to spicy on the pocket book! The Cubase LE 4 program that came with the interface is compatable with windows XP and Vista. Cubase 5 and 6 look good but I dont have that kind of money. I'm looking to produce CDs for a Gospel quartet.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all the major DAW's offer some kind of lite version for a cheap price. Examples are [Cubase 4 LE](http://www.steinberg.net/en/support/downloads/downloads_cle4.html) (which I would expect to work on Win 7), or Cakewalk [SONAR X1 Essential](http://www.cakewalk.com/products/sonar/x1-Essential/). But my recommendation goes to [REAPER](http://www.reaper.fm/), a very powerful, fully featured DAW, available for a bargain price ($40 non-commercial licence, $150 full licence). It's free to try, so I'd recommend you give it a go.

Comment: Reaper is freaking awesome!